# Permissions on Time Machine backups

Tags: time-machine, permission

I have two external USB3 disks, each with a Time Machine (TM) backupDB directory.  When both are mounted, backups alternate.

Both disks are browsable by Finder from admin account.  But the backup directories differ: one is browsable in Finder by the admin account, the other is not.  Also, in the one that is readable, the directory containing the backups is named after the internal SSD; in the other, it is named after the laptop itself.

Why would these differences exist?  Can they be changed to match without major hassle?